# Encode string data between PHP and Python

Tags: php, python, character-encoding

What would be the best way or a simple and good way to encode string data in python for later reading in php?

Failed examples:

1: In Python:

```
>>> encoded = u'test ö'.encode('utf-8')
'text \xc3\xb6'
```

In PHP:

```
>>> $decoded = utf8_decode('test \xc3\xb6');
test \xc3\xb6
```

???

2: In Python:

```
>>> encoded = u'test ö'.encode('latin-1')
'test \xf6'
```

In PHP:

> > > $decoded = ???;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double quotes to get backslash escape sequences parsed in PHP.

```
# php -r 'echo utf8_decode("test \xc3\xb6");'
test ö
```

And using UTF8 is certainly one of the most interoperable ways to pass string data between programming languages / systems / etc.